# libGDX Draw Part of a TextureRegion

Tags: java, libgdx

I am making a tile based game and part of my entity sprites have textures that are slightly larger than a tile. I am trying to draw part of the `TextureRegion` below the player, so the top of the player is above it, and another part of the texture region below the player, so the player is behind it.

The texture for the sprite is a sprite sheet with four different parts for the four directions, and when the entity changes direction a `TextureRegion` gets set to the part of the sprite sheet I want to draw.

I have been able to get part of the sprite do draw in front and behind the player but the `TextureRegion` is not the part of the sprite sheet that corresponds to the direction.

This is what I have so far:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        mapBatch.draw(characters[i].getSprite().getTexture(), characters[i].getSprite().getX(), characters[i].getSprite().getY(), characters[i].getSprite().getRegionX(), characters[i].getSprite().getRegionY() + 5, 16, 16);
    }
    player.draw(mapBatch);
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        mapBatch.draw(characters[i].getSprite().getTexture(), characters[i].getSprite().getX(), characters[i].getSprite().getY() + 16, characters[i].getSprite().getRegionX(), characters[i].getSprite().getRegionY(), 16, 5);
    }
```

This is the sprite sheet with the four different directions

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6jf2wJpNtOSbVVYcHlja2x6Nkk

Comment: Not  enough detail to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Essentially I want part of the sprites texture to render behind the player, and part to render in front

Comment: That much is clear, but what part of the texture region, is it a rectangular region, what do you mean by four different parts/directions, what does it even look like? With the detail you've provided, all I can say is draw the *behind* texture regions before drawing the player and draw the *in front* texture regions after drawing the player. There are straight-forward methods available in the TextureRegion class for dividing up a Texture or TextureRegion into recatangles. Or SpriteBatch has draw() methods that take UV coordinates.

Comment: I added a link to the image file I am using, I want to draw the bottom 16x16 square of each direction the character is facing behind the player, and the last top 5x16 rectangle of each direction in front of the player

Comment: Essentially Texture is the whole psrite sheet.  TextureRegions were created so that parts of the Texture can be separately controlled.  So you would not split up a TextureRegion per se, you would split up a Texture into TextureRegions.

Comment: It looks like `mapBatch` is `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch`.  But we shouldn't be guessing about this stuff.  Please include definitions of `player`, `characters`, `mapBatch` etc so we're not guessing.

Comment: mapBatch is a SpriteBatch, player and characters are sprites

Comment: @JoseMartinez I am able to split the texture into texture regions for the four directions, but what is drawn is just the part of the texture where the character is facing up

Comment: Won't be able to see the Google drive till I get home form work.  Anyway you can paste to this question the outcome that appears on your screen?